# How can I convert any string to an integer?

Tags: c#, string, int, converters, currency

How can i convert from example "1.234.567.890 VNĐ" or any string not in a correct number format.
output: 1234567890

I try: int.Parse, convert.ToInt32 or int.tryParse, double,.... But not working.

Comment: Hi! Please tag your question with the language you're using -- it makes it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: You should really mention more details, before some down votes this question. "Which programming language?" for starters.

Comment: you could possibly loop through the string and delete characters, so you end up with a string 1234567890. Then you could use a wrapper class to convert it to integer. I am talking about java now

Comment: How about return 0. Not the answer you were hoping for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the integer numbers that are contained within a `string`, you can just loop through the `string` and take all numbers.

```
string yourString = "1.234.567.890 VNĐ";
string tmpString = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < yourString.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(yourString, i))
    {
       tmpString += yourString[i];
    }
}
int finalInt = int.Parse(tmpString);
```

`char.IsDigit(string, int)`  [(see documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58.aspx) checks if the `char` at position `i` in the string is a digit (not only 0..9, but also other numbers). If that's the case, add it to your string. At the end, you have all your numbers and can cast them to `int`.